# Why i can't use multiple or nested Domain?

Tags: xml, odoo

I try to use multiple or nested domain but it's doesn't work ??

```
['|',('a','=',5),('&amp;',('b','!=',10),('c','=','12'))]
```

and i got the error with last parentheses

> ValueError: Invalid leaf [u'&', [u'b', u'!=', 10], [u'c', u'=', 12']]

*Some one please help me and thank you for you time to rend my word (sorry about my language :'|)*

Comment: First of all please use "in" instead of "=" and "not" instead of "!=" and then please remove inverted comma from 12. then try.!

Comment: ['|',('a','in',5),('&amp;',('b','not in',10),('c','in', 12))] like this ?

Comment: `in` use when we have multiple values or states. For example. `a` has value `10` and you need to check value of a, than syntax will become `domain=['a','in', (1,10,5)]` or for example, `[('type','in',['draft','open','paid'])]`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax isn't correct, you should use `['|',('a','=',5),'&amp;',('b','!=',10),('c','=',12)]` without the parentises on the & clause.
Domain use Polish (prefix) notation that removes ambiguities from expressions by putting the operator always before the pair of operands on wich it is supposed to act uppon.

Example, if you want to make this operation: `(6 - 3) x 4`, in prefix notation you will simply do this: `x - 6 3 4`

In your case, since you want `condition A or (condition B and condition C)` you have to write `or condition A and condition B condition C`

Comment: `domain="['|', ('partner_id', '=', partner_id),('state', '=', 'open'),'&amp;' ('filed_name.type','!=,'invoice')]"` it's not error but "filed_name.type != invoice" still appear :'(

Comment: also `domain="['&amp;', ('filed_name.type','!=,'invoice'), '|', ('partner_id', '=', partner_id),('state', '=', 'open')]"` what should i do ?

Comment: Try changing your unquoted partner_id to uid, e.g. `['&amp;', ('filed_name.type','!=','invoice'), '|', ('partner_id', '=', uid),('state', '=', 'open')]`

Comment: ิbut uid it's a user, right? and partner it's about customer or suppiler.